# JPA insert operation is not working properly

Tags: oracle, jpa, insert, entity, jpa-2.1

Need to perform insert operation

```
Member {
  member_id // have one to one relation with student_id and teacher_id ( sharing primary key)
  lastupdateddate
  latupdatedby
}

Student {
  student_id // have one to one relation with member_id
  student name
  lastupdateddate
  latupdatedby
}

Teacher {
  teacher_id // have one to one relation ship with member_id
  teacher name
  lastupdateddate
  latupdatedby
}

Address {
  address id
  member_id // have one to one relationship with member_id class
  lastupdateddate
  latupdatedby
}
```

When I persist student details, the address related info is not properly inserted.When I check insert queries fired on member, then student and after on address table. But, in the insert query to address table, the member_id value is coming as null.Because of this only address table is not populated.

Entity structure is is as given below

```
public abstract class Member implements Serializable {
}
public class Student extends Member implements Serializable {
}
public class Teacher extends Member implements Serializable {
}
public class Address implements Serializable {
}
```

The mapping is mentioned as given below. Tried out various available options.

In member entity class:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="member", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Address address;
```

In address entity class:

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "MEMBER_ID")
private Address address;
```

Do I missing anything in entity level or is this the correct to way to do this?
The entity is saving using saveAndFlush operation of JpaRepository.

Comment: Is address set in the member you pass to JPA and vice versa?

Comment: Yes, I found the problem. You are correct. member was not set in address object, that only created the issue.